Monitor Firmware String extraction
I have Monitor firmware that doesn't recognize by the binwalk and unable to extract file system of it. i want to extract data and string of firmware.
anyone have experience please help me.
The firmware belongs to several monitors of samsung and LG company. that's same for all. binwalk prompt me empty!

thanks Robert, edited

Where do you get the firmware data from? May be the firmware is encrypted compressed or obscured before installation.

I captured bin file using hardware programmer

I opened it using ollydbg and that's right, it's obfuscated. how to send it for you or upload on stackexchange
